# Not find page disappears when refreshing react subpage

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using react router and I build my project uploaded to my web hosting and when I'm on some subpage and refresh it then not found page disappears.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import{ BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link, BrowserRouter} from 
'react-router-dom';

import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<Router ><App /></Router>, 
document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

here is my how my app.js looks like:

```
        <div className="App" >


        <Header  />

        <Route exact path="/" component={Homepage} />
        <Route exact path='/Kontakt' component={Kontakt}/>
        <Route  path='/Kontaktformular' component={Kontaktformular} />
        <Route  path='/Agatoveihriska' component={Agatoveihriska} />
        <Route  path='/Fitnessworkout' component={Fitnessworkout} />
        <Route  path='/Referencie' component={Referencie} />
        <Route  path='/Hraciezostavy' component={Hraciezostavy} />
        <Route  path='/Domcekyaltanky' component={Domcekyaltanky} />
        <Route  path='/Hojdackylavice' component={Hojdackylavice} />


        { window.location.pathname === "/" || window.location.pathname === "/Kontakt" ? null : <Kontaktformular /> }


    </div>
```

Comment: You will need to add much more (including code) before we are able to help you effectively here.

Comment: This appear to be the same question (also without code) that you asked two days ago.

Comment: added my index.js code hope it helps

Comment: please share your routes code along with wrapper

Comment: I added everything i have i think

Comment: i think its a more serve side issue. what is your server ? did u hanlde routing there ?

Comment: no i did nothing but im using apache, maybe something to do with httacces ?